# Linear-time constant-space 1/2-approximation algorithm for the maximum subset sum problem

Tags: algorithms, approximation, greedy-algorithms, subset-sum

The following problem statement is given:
Let $S = \{s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n\}$ be a sequence of unique positive integers and $K$ a positive integer, where $K \ge s_i$ for every $i$ between $1$ and $n$.  The goal is to find a subset of $S$ whose sum is maximum, subject to the constraint that the sum must be $\le K$.
Write an approximation algorithm which computes a sum which is at least half of the optimal solution on any given input. This algorithm must run in $O(n)$ time-complexity and $O(1)$ space-complexity.

I've been searching for some simple algorithm to satisfy these conditions and the closest I've come to is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximation_algorithms), but since it makes use of sorting, the time-complexity is brought to $O(n\log n)$.

This is taken from a set of exercises given by my uni professor as preparation for the final exam. To be honest, I am not sure whether it is his original work or not, so I don't have any relevant reference to provide.

Comment: Please credit the source where you encountered this problem statement: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: The problem statement is not clear, as it doesn't define what is meant by the optimal solution.  Please make sure the body of the post is self-contained and contains enough information to answer the question.  I encourage you to edit the question to address this feedback.

Comment: I've made an edit to try to clarify what might be the question.  Please check whether that represents your problem statement (and if not, edit it appropriately), and [edit] your question to credit the source where you saw this.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and sorry for the untimely response. @D.W. your edit is correct and I modified my question to try and specify the source. My prof. is pretty old school and I wouldn't mention his name here, nor would I even attempt to ask him for permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to set $K/2$ as the target.

- If there is any given number that is at least $K/2$, just return it.
- Otherwise, all given numbers are $<K/2$.

  - If the sum of all given numbers is $\le K$, return the sum, which is the optimal solution.
  - Otherwise the sum of all given numbers is $>K$.
    Let $prefix\_sum$ be $0$ initially. We will try adding all given numbers one by one to $prefix\_sum$ until it is $\ge K/2$, at which moment it cannot be $>K$ -- otherwise the last number added must be $>K/2$. Return it.

---

Here is an algorithm that implements the idea concisely. It runs in $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ space.

1. Let $prefix\_sum = 0$.
2. For $i$ from $1$ to $n$:

   1. If $s_i\ge K/2$, return $s_i$. Else add $s_i$ to $prefix\_sum$.
   2. If $prefix\_sum\ge K/2$, return $prefix\_sum$.
3. Return $prefix\_sum$.

Comment: Thank you very much. All I was thinking about was different ways in which to search for the right combination of elements. It never occurred to me that just changing the target would do it.

Comment: You are welcome.